# How to fold over a constructor with special cases?

Tags: haskell, generics, scrap-your-boilerplate

So I have a tree that I want to collapse where the nodes are of type

```
data Node = Node1 Node | Node2 Node Node | ... deriving Data
```

except for a few special cases. I want to do something along the lines of

```
collapse SPECIALCASE1 = ...
collapse SPECIALCASE2 = ...
...
collapse node = foldl (++) $ gmapQ validate node
```

where all the special cases generate lists of results that the last case just recursively collapses; but this doesn't work as the function that is the first parameter of gmapQ has to be of type `forall d. Data d => d -> u` and not `Node -> u`, which as far as I know just limits you to only using functions operating on the `Data` type.

Is there any way of coercing the values in the problem to be of the correct type, or another more lenient map function perhaps?

Extra info:

The actual code for the function described above as `collapse` is named `validate` and is for traversing and finding unbound variables in an abstract syntax tree (for a very simple language) for which the special cases are handled like this

```
validate _ (Nr _) = []
validate env (Let var val expr) = validate env val ++ validate (var:env) expr
validate env (Var var) = if elem var env then [] else [var]
```

which is essentially the rules that literal numbers don't have variables in them, let expressions binds a variable and variables need to be checked if bound or not. Every other construct in this toy-language is just a combination of numbers and variables (e.g. summation, multiplication, etc.) and as such when I check for unbound variables I just need to traverse their sub-trees and combine the results; thus the `gmapQ`.

Extra info 2:

The actual data type used instead of the `Node` example above is of the form

```
data Ast = Nr Int
         | Sum Ast Ast
         | Mul Ast Ast
         | Min Ast
         | If Ast Ast Ast
         | Let String Ast Ast
         | Var String
           deriving (Show, Eq, Data)
```

Comment: What do you need all this fancy generic stuff for when you know the type? Why not write it precisely as you have (pattern matching), and perhaps skip the `gmapQ` altogether?

Comment: Mostly all of the `NodeX` constructors have this repeated pattern of sub-nodes I showed above, and writing patterns for every one of them would be very redundant; which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Well, nothing stops you from combining the approaches by dispatching "manually" to one or more generic helpers.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I could try to be more specific if you provide more code, like how you'd write one or two of the special cases by hand.

Comment: Added some code as an edit now =)

Comment: What's `collapse` about then? Is it used somewhere in the definition of `validate`? What's your AST type actually look like? All this general vagueness is rather unhelpful!

Comment: `collapse` was just a term I made up when I described the problem; as the `validate` function essentially collapses a tree I felt it sensible to name it `collapse` for generalities sake. For that matter the actual abstract syntax tree isn't made up of `Node1`, `Node2`, etc, but more sensibly named constructors like `Sum`, and `Multiply`, etc.

Comment: Added the definition of the data type as well =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct way to do what you want is to write your special case for `validate` as:

```
validate env expr = concat $ gmapQ ([] `mkQ` (validate env)) expr
```

This uses `mkQ` from `Data.Generics.Aliases`.  The whole point of `mkQ` is to create queries of type `forall d. Data d => d -> u` that can operate differently on different `Data` instances.  By the way, there's no magic here.  You could have defined it manually in terms of `cast` as:

```
validate env expr = concat $ gmapQ myQuery expr
  where myQuery :: Data d => d -> [String]
        myQuery d = case cast d of Just d -> validate env d
                                   _ -> []
```

Still, I've generally found it clearer to use `uniplate` from the `lens` library.  The idea is to create a default `Plated` instance:

```
instance Plated Ast where
  plate = uniplate   -- uniplate from Data.Data.Lens
```

which magically defines `children :: Ast -> [Ast]` to return all direct descendants of a node.  You can then write your default `validate` case as:

```
validate env expr = concatMap (validate env) (children expr)
```

The full code w/ a test that prints ["z"]:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

module SpecialCase where

import Control.Lens.Plated
import Data.Data
import Data.Data.Lens (uniplate)

data Ast = Nr Int
         | Sum Ast Ast
         | Mul Ast Ast
         | Min Ast
         | If Ast Ast Ast
         | Let String Ast Ast
         | Var String
           deriving (Show, Eq, Data)

instance Plated Ast where
  plate = uniplate

validate env (Let var val expr) = validate env val ++ validate (var:env) expr
validate env (Var var) = if elem var env then [] else [var]
-- either use this uniplate version:
validate env expr = concatMap (validate env) (children expr)
-- or use the alternative, lens-free version:
-- validate env expr = concat $ gmapQ ([] `mkQ` (validate env)) expr

main = print $ validate [] (Let "x" (Nr 3) (Let "y" (Var "x") 
             (Sum (Mul (Var "x") (Var "z")) (Var "y"))))
```

Comment: So this lens is a third party library, or what? I can only use the standard library as this is for some homework; so I guess i'll have do the `mkQ` version. And yes this seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I was too slow to get a `Data`-based answer written before K. A. Buhr jumped on it. Here's another approach, based on `recursion-schemes`.

First, the boilerplate:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies
           , DeriveTraversable #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH

data Ast = Nr Int
         | Sum Ast Ast
         | Mul Ast Ast
         | Min Ast
         | If Ast Ast Ast
         | Let String Ast Ast
         | Var String
         deriving (Show, Eq)

makeBaseFunctor ''Ast
```

This creates a type `AstF` that takes the recursion out of `Ast`. It looks like this:

```
data AstF ast = NrF Int
              | SumF ast ast
              | MulF ast ast
              ....
              deriving (Functor,Foldable,Traversable)
```

It then also creates several instances. We'll be using two of the auto-generated instances: the `Recursive` instance of `Ast` to recursively validate the tree, and the `Foldable` instance of `AstF` to concatenate the results from the children in the default case.

I found it helpful to create a separate type for environments; this is quite optional.

```
newtype Env = Env {getEnv :: [String]}

emptyEnv :: Env
emptyEnv = Env []

extendEnv :: String -> Env -> Env
extendEnv a (Env as) = Env (a : as)

isFree :: String -> Env -> Bool
isFree a (Env as) = not (elem a as)
```

Now we can get down to business, using the `Recursive` instance of `Ast` to get `cata` for free.

```
validate :: Env -> Ast -> [String]
validate env0 ast0 = cata go ast0 env0
  where
    go :: AstF (Env -> [String]) -> Env -> [String]
    go (LetF var val expr) env = val env ++ expr (extendEnv var env)
    go (VarF var) env = [var | isFree var env]
    go expr env = foldMap id expr env
```

Comment: I think this is probably as much boilerplate as the repeated code I was trying to avoid, but I'll read up on it a bit and see if this comes in handy somewhere =)

Comment: @AndreasHagen, most of the boilerplate is generated automatically by the call to `makeBaseFunctor ''Ast`. You don't have to write the `AstF` type or any of its instances. You also don't need the `Env` stuff I stuck in to make the code (I thought) clearer. The big advantage, I think, is that the operation is a lot less mysterious magic than what `Data` gives you.